# Flink best way to group records by field id

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm setting up Apache Flink connected with Kafka broker.

I got a the following messages in random order:

- message(timestamp=[..], index=1, someData=[..])
- message(timestamp=[..], index=2, someData=[..])
- message(timestamp=[..], index=3, someData=[..])
- message(timestamp=[..], index=2, someData=[..])
- message(timestamp=[..], index=3, someData=[..])
- message(timestamp=[..], index=1, someData=[..])

My records coming from Kafka got a `index` field.

In my application, i need to compute last two of these records that have a same id and then immediately send the response.

For example, these two:

- message(timestamp=[..], index=1, someData=[..])
- message(timestamp=[..], index=1, someData=[..])

Whats the best way to store and compute last two records with the same index field? Could you tell me some tips?

Comment: When you say "last 2 events", is it according to event-time (timestamp field) or processing-time?

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements aren't entirely clear, but the mechanisms you probably want to understand are using `keyBy(e -> e.index)` to group/partition the stream by the index field, and [keyed state](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state/state.html#keyed-state) for remembering the last event (or two) for each value of the index.

If you need to take the timestamps into account, and the event stream is out-of-order, even within a single value of the index, then you will need to first sort the stream by the timestamps. In that case you'll have a much easier time if you use Flink SQL to do the sorting, and then you could use [match_recognize](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/streaming/match_recognize.html) to do the pattern recognition, though that's perhaps overkill for such a simple pattern. Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54970489/2000823) of how to do the sorting.