# How do I handle out-of-order events with Apache flink?

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming, stream-processing

To test out stream processing and Flink, I have given myself a seemingly simple problem. My Data stream consists of `x` and `y` coordinates for a particle along with time `t` at which the position was recorded. My objective is to annotate this data with velocity of the particular particle. So the stream might look some thing like this.

```
<timestamp:Long> <particle_id:String> <x:Double> <y:Double>

1612103771212 p1 0.0 0.0
1612103771212 p2 0.0 0.0
1612103771213 p1 0.1 0.1
1612103771213 p2 -0.1 -0.1
1612103771214 p1 0.1 0.2
1612103771214 p2 -0.1 -0.2
1612103771215 p1 0.2 0.2
1612103771215 p2 -0.2 -0.2
```

Now there is no guaranty that the events would arrive in order i.e. `1612103771213 p2 -0.1 -0.1` might arrive say `10ms` before `1612103771212 p2 0.0 0.0`.

For simplicity, it can be assumed that any late data will arrive within `100ms` of the early data.

I will admit that I am new to stream processing and Flink, so this might be a stupid question to ask with an obvious answer, but I am currently stumped as to how to go about achieving my objective here.

**EDIT**

Following David's answer I tried using Flink Table API to sort the Datastream, using `nc -lk 9999` for text socket stream. The issue is that nothing gets printed to the console until I close the text socket stream. Here is the scala code I wrote -

```scala
package processor

import org.apache.flink.api.common.eventtime.{SerializableTimestampAssigner, WatermarkStrategy}
import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.MapFunction
import org.apache.flink.api.common.state.{ValueState, ValueStateDescriptor}
import org.apache.flink.api.scala.typeutils.Types
import org.apache.flink.configuration.Configuration
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.KeyedProcessFunction
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._
import org.apache.flink.table.api.bridge.scala.StreamTableEnvironment
import org.apache.flink.table.api.{EnvironmentSettings, FieldExpression, WithOperations}
import org.apache.flink.util.Collector

import java.time.Duration


object AnnotateJob {

  val OUT_OF_ORDER_NESS = 100

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    // set up the streaming execution environment
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

    val bSettings = EnvironmentSettings.newInstance().useBlinkPlanner().inStreamingMode().build()

    val tableEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env, bSettings)

    env.setParallelism(1)

    // Obtain the input data by connecting to the socket. Here you want to connect to the local 9999 port.
    val text = env.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999)
    val objStream = text
      .filter( _.nonEmpty )
      .map(new ParticleMapFunction)

    val posStream = objStream
      .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(
        WatermarkStrategy
          .forBoundedOutOfOrderness[ParticlePos](Duration.ofMillis(OUT_OF_ORDER_NESS))
          .withTimestampAssigner(new SerializableTimestampAssigner[ParticlePos] {
            override def extractTimestamp(t: ParticlePos, l: Long): Long = t.t
          })
      )

    val tablePos = tableEnv.fromDataStream(posStream, $"t".rowtime() as "et", $"t", $"name", $"x", $"y")
    tableEnv.createTemporaryView("pos", tablePos)
    val sorted = tableEnv.sqlQuery("SELECT t, name, x, y FROM pos ORDER BY et ASC")

    val sortedPosStream = tableEnv.toAppendStream[ParticlePos](sorted)

    // sortedPosStream.keyBy(pos => pos.name).process(new ValAnnotator)

    sortedPosStream.print()

    // execute program
    env.execute()
  }

  case class ParticlePos(t : Long, name : String, x : Double, y : Double) extends Serializable
  case class ParticlePosVal(t : Long, name : String, x : Double, y : Double,
                            var vx : Double = 0.0, var vy : Double = 0.0) extends Serializable

  class ParticleMapFunction extends MapFunction[String, ParticlePos] {
    override def map(t: String): ParticlePos = {
      val parts = t.split("\\W+")
      ParticlePos(parts(0).toLong, parts(1), parts(2).toDouble, parts(3).toDouble)
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, watermarks in combination with event-time timers are the solution to the problems posed by out-of-order event streams. The section of the official Flink training that covers [Event Time and Watermarks](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/learn-flink/streaming_analytics/) explains how this works.

At a higher level it is sometimes easier to use something like Flink's CEP library, or Flink SQL, because they make it very easy to sort a stream by time, thus removing all of the out-of-orderness. For example, see [How to sort a stream by event time using Flink SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54970489/2000823) for an example of a Flink DataStream program that uses Flink SQL to sort a stream by event time.

In your case, a fairly simple [MATCH_RECOGNIZE](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/streaming/match_recognize.html) query would do what you're looking for. That might look something like this,

```sql
SELECT *
    FROM event
    MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
        PARTITION BY particleId
        ORDER BY ts
        MEASURES 
            b.ts, 
            b.particleId, 
            velocity(a, b)
        AFTER MATCH SKIP TO NEXT ROW
        PATTERN (a b)
        DEFINE
            a AS TRUE,
            b AS TRUE
    )
```

where velocity(a, b) is a user-defined function that computes the velocity, given two sequential events (a and b) for the same particle.

Comment: Hey David I followed the post that you had linked, and tried to implement the solution there for my use case, using a socket for my datastream, the thing is nothing gets printed to the console until i close the socket connection, I have edited my question with the code I am using, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: This means that the first watermark your job sees is the one generated by the socket closing, which injects a watermark for time MAX_WATERMARK. Probably one of two things is preventing earlier watermarks from being created: either there is no event with a sufficiently large enough timestamp, or the job isn't being left running long enough (by default, the bounded-out-of-orderness strategy is called every 200 msec for a new watermark).

Comment: Thanks David, I didn't have any events with large enough timestamp i can see the output now

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing this in Flink might be to use a [KeyedProcessFunction](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/process_function.html#the-keyedprocessfunction), i.e. a function that can:

- process each event in your stream
- maintain some state
- trigger some logic with a timer based on event time

So it would go something like this:

- you need to know some kind of "max out of orderness" about your data. Based on your description, let's assume 100ms for example, such that when processing data at timestamp `1612103771212` you decide to consider you're sure to have received all data until `1612103771112`.
- your first step is to `keyBy()` your stream, keying by particle id. This means that the logic of next operators in your Flink application can now be expressed in terms of a sequence of events of just one particle, and each particle is processed in this manner in parallel.

Something like this:

```
yourStream.keyBy(...lookup p1 or p2 here...).process(new YourProcessFunction())
```

- during the initialization of the `ProcessFunction` of `YourProcessFunction` (i.e. during the `open` method), initialize a `ListState` where you can safely store stuff.
- when processing an element in your stream, in the `processElement` method, just add it to the `listState` and register a timer trigger in, say, 100ms
- when the `onTimer()` method triggers, say at time `t`, look at all elements in the `listState` that have a time < `t - 100` and, if you have at least two of them, sort them, remove them from the state, apply the speed calculation and annotation logic you described, and emit the result downstream.

You'll find [an example in the official Flink training](https://github.com/apache/flink-training/blob/master/long-ride-alerts/src/solution/java/org/apache/flink/training/solutions/longrides/LongRidesSolution.java#L64) that is using this kind of logic for the duration of taxi rides, which has lot's of similarities with your use case. Have also a look at the various Readme.md files of that repo for more details.

Comment: already doing `keyBy(particleID)`, I'll go through the flink training example and see how it can be applied to my case